# Can't start AVD Emulator in eclipse android project?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create a android application.I installed the tools and other thinks. But if i try to start avd then it shows error like bellow.

```
Starting emulator for AVD '4_7WXGA_API'
/home/anand/Android//tools/emulator: 1: /home/anand/Android//tools/emulator: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I don't know what to do can any one help me to fix this

Thank You

Comment: Check your sdk path set in the Window-->Preference-->Android-->SDK Location. if any space in start or end then this issue occurs

Comment: @PravinFofariya My android location is /home/anand/Android there is no space

Comment: In Window menu-->Preference-->then left side you can see the Android--> then see right size SDK Location check path or reset it

Comment: Did you update your android studio/avd or intel haxm?